# Loacation Counters and Code Segment

Tags: assembly

How these location counters have been calculate for code segment :

```
 0000               codesg Segment
                Assume cs:codesg,ds:datasg
 0000               Main proc Far
 0000  B8 ---- R            mov ax,seg datasg
 0003  8B D0                mov dx,ax
 0005  A1 000A R            mov ax,b2+2
 0008  50               push ax
 0009  A1 000A R        l1: mov ax,x
 000C  40               inc ax
 000D  3C 05                cmp al,5
 000F  75 09                jne l2
 0011  8B 0E 0008 R         mov cx,a2+2
 0015  E2 F2                loop l1
 0017  B8 0000              mov ax,0
 001A  CB           l2: ret
 001B               main endp
 001B               codesg ends
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add the number of bytes in the current instruction to the current location counter and that becomes the new location counter. So if you start at location 0 and you have a 3 byte instruction then the location counter for the next instruction will be 3.